# How to optimize the parameters of extended merkle signature scheme?

Tags: hash-signature

Given the parameters which include: tree height, Winternitz parameter, security parameter, SHA-512 or SHA-256, tree level, how do I optimize the scheme to output a small signature?

The idea is to reduce latency of Extended Merkle Signature Scheme to be use in bitcoin cryptosystem.

Comment: Optimize for what?  Signature size?  Signature generation time?  Signature verification time?  Security strength?

Comment: Is not clear what are you asking, probably you should clarify your question.

Comment: Optimized for signature size.. (The aim is to reduce latency of Extended Merkle Signature Scheme to be use in bitcoin cryptosystem)

Comment: This is a question that can be answered, but I don't see any effort has been taken place. It is possible to at least get some ideas about the parameters that can be chosen, right? As it stands, it seems more like a task than a concise question.